# opening HTML links from local HTML UIWebVIew in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have an app that is made of local HTML files.

All the tel: links and mailto: work fine, and open the telephone and mail on iOS, but when I use a simple HTML link to a website, nothing happens,

Here is my code, any input would be appreciated.

Regards

Sam

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  LoadLocalHtml
//
//  Created by Farhad on 9/20/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 WebInDream. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadHtmlFile()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadHtmlFile() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
        webView.isOpaque = false;
    }

}
```

here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested. here is the HTML code as requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>



    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="fullset">

            <div class="container_header">
            <p><strong>LOCATIONS</strong></p>

            </div>

            <div class="container">
            <p><strong>HEAD OFFICE</strong><br>35 Headlands<br>Kettering<br>Northamptonshire<br>NN15 7ES</p>
            <a href="tel:01536513165"><p>T: 01536 513 165</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p><strong>HARROGATE</strong><br>The Tower Studio<br>Fourth Avenue, Hornbeam Park<br>Harrogate<br>HG2 8QT</p>
                <a href="tel:01423815121"><p>T: 01423 815 121</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p><strong>GLOUCESTER</strong><br>North Warehouse<br>Gloucester Docks<br>Gloucester<br>GL1 2EP</p>
                <a href="tel:01452525019"><p>T: 01452 525 019</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p><strong>MILTON KEYNES</strong><br>Exchange House<br>494 Midsummer Boulevard<br>Milton Keynes<br>MK9 2EA</p>
                <a href="tel:01908255620"><p>T: 01908 255 620</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <p><strong>NEWCASTLE</strong><br>Hoults Yard<br>Walker Road<br>Newcastle<br>NE6 2HL</p>
                <a href="tel:01913898917"><p>T: 0191 389 8917</p></a>
            </div>

            <div class="container_header">
            <p><strong>CONTACT DETAILS</strong></p>
            </div>



            <div class="container">
                <p><strong>EMAIL </strong><a href="mailto:gss@gotch.co.uk">gss@gotch.co.uk</a><br>
                <strong>WEB </strong><a href="http://www.gssarchitecture.com">gssarchitecture.com</a><br>
                <strong>TWITTER </strong><a href="http://www.gssarchitecture.com">@GSSARCHITECTURE</a><br>
                <strong>LINKEDIN </strong><a href="http://www.gssarchitecture.com">COMPANY PROFILE</a>
                </p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="returnbar">
            <a class="returnlink" href="index.html" style="text-align:center">Return to Previous Menu</a>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code?

Comment: have added in the main original post

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` and assign delegate to your `webview` like  `webview.delegate = self` to identify clicked link 
Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        webview.delegate = self
        loadHtmlFile()
    }

    func loadHtmlFile() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)

        webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
        webView.isOpaque = false;

    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == .linkClicked {
            if let url = request.url {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: hi jignesh, thanks for replying. however unfortunately this didn't do anything, don't suppose you have any other suggestions

Comment: this method call or not ?


webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)

Comment: hi jignesh, many thanks this does work, but has now killed links to local html files within the app!

Comment: you want to open clicked link in same webview right?

Comment: i have 3 kinds of links.

links to local html files within the app, links to external websites, and links to tel numbers. your suggestion lets the links to external websites and tel numbers work but the locals stop working

FINE
<strong>EMAIL </strong><a href="mailto:gss@gotch.co.uk">gss@gotch.co.uk</a><br>
                <strong>WEB </strong><a href="http://www.gssarchitecture.com">gssarchitecture.com</a><br>
                <strong>TWITTER </strong>

BROKEN
<a class="returnlink" href="index.html" style="text-align:center">Return to Previous Menu</a>

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Manser  Try  to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. As UIWebView is Dperected from iOS 11. When you tap on your link, It's navigating to safari browser perfect.

**Swift 4**

```
     import UIKit
     import WebKit

     class ViewController: UIViewController , WKUIDelegate , WKNavigationDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var indeWebView: WKWebView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            loadButtonHTMLFile()
        }


        func loadButtonHTMLFile() {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension:"html")
            indeWebView.uiDelegate = self
            indeWebView.navigationDelegate = self
            indeWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
            indeWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        }

        //Open Tapped Link in Safari
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {

            if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated {
                if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
            // Call this completion handler compulsary
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
        }
     }
```